# Sliding images doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I have two Java Classes. The first activity is the `MainActivity` which is the NavigationView Activity named HomeScreen. In the content_layout I added `Sliding Images Layout` logic of which is implemented in a new class named `Slider`.

When I run the app, the layout for the sliding images is empty. I think I have to "combine" these two activities so when I run the app, `Slider` will also work to make the sliding images appeared and working.

Here is my code logic -

**HomeScreen Activity**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout;

import static com.pertanian.puslitbangbun.fixyou.Login.my_shared_preferences;
import static com.pertanian.puslitbangbun.fixyou.Login.session_status;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    Boolean session = false;
    Slider slider;

    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(my_shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        session = sharedpreferences.getBoolean(session_status, false);
        if (session) {
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.admin).setVisible(false);
        }
        else {
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setMessage("Anda yakin ingin keluar?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.artikel) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (id == R.id.puslitbangbun) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Pemberlitri.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (id == R.id.balittro) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (id == R.id.balittri) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (id == R.id.balittas) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (id == R.id.balitpalma) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (id == R.id.tentang) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Tentang.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (id == R.id.admin) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (id == R.id.logout) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setMessage("Anda yakin ingin Logout?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(Login.session_status, false);
                    editor.putString(TAG_ID, null);
                    editor.putString(TAG_USERNAME, null);
                    editor.apply();

                    startActivity(new Intent(HomeScreen.this, HomeScreen.class));

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Slider.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.daimajia.slider.library.Animations.DescriptionAnimation;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.BaseSliderView;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.TextSliderView;
import com.daimajia.slider.library.Tricks.ViewPagerEx;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Slider extends AppCompatActivity
        implements BaseSliderView.OnSliderClickListener,
        ViewPagerEx.OnPageChangeListener
{

    SliderLayout sliderLayout ;

    HashMap<String, String> HashMapForURL ;
    HashMap<String, Integer> HashMapForLocalRes ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_home_screen);

        sliderLayout = findViewById(R.id.slider);

        //Call this method if you want to add images from URL .
        //AddImagesUrlOnline();

        //Call this method to add images from local drawable folder .
        AddImageUrlFormLocalRes();

        //Call this method to stop automatic sliding.
        //sliderLayout.stopAutoCycle();

        for(String name : HashMapForLocalRes.keySet()){

            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(Slider.this);

            textSliderView
                    .description(name)
                    .image(HashMapForLocalRes.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(this);

            textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());

            textSliderView.getBundle()
                    .putString("extra",name);

            sliderLayout.addSlider(textSliderView);
        }
        sliderLayout.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.DepthPage);
        sliderLayout.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
        sliderLayout.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
        sliderLayout.setDuration(3000);
        sliderLayout.startAutoCycle();
        sliderLayout.addOnPageChangeListener(Slider.this);
    }

    //@Override
    //protected void onStop() {

    //  sliderLayout.stopAutoCycle();

    //super.onStop();
    //}

    @Override
    public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {

        Toast.makeText(this,slider.getBundle().get("extra") + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        Log.d("Slider Demo", "Page Changed: " + position);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }

    public void AddImagesUrlOnline(){

        HashMapForURL = new HashMap<>();

        HashMapForURL.put("CupCake", "http://androidblog.esy.es/images/cupcake-1.png");
        HashMapForURL.put("Donut", "http://androidblog.esy.es/images/donut-2.png");
        HashMapForURL.put("Eclair", "http://androidblog.esy.es/images/eclair-3.png");
        HashMapForURL.put("Froyo", "http://androidblog.esy.es/images/froyo-4.png");
        HashMapForURL.put("GingerBread", "http://androidblog.esy.es/images/gingerbread-5.png");
    }

    public void AddImageUrlFormLocalRes(){

        HashMapForLocalRes = new HashMap<>();

        HashMapForLocalRes.put("CupCake", R.drawable.bgall);
        HashMapForLocalRes.put("Donut", R.drawable.bgadmin);
        HashMapForLocalRes.put("Eclair", R.drawable.bgall);
        HashMapForLocalRes.put("Froyo", R.drawable.bgadmin);
        HashMapForLocalRes.put("GingerBread", R.drawable.bgall);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in this line

```
startActivity(new Intent(HomeScreen.this, HomeScreen.class));
```

rather it should be

```
startActivity(new Intent(HomeScreen.this, Slider.class));
```

Comment: It isn't. It's for the logout confirmation so if Yes is clicked, the HomeScreen activity will refresh and the admin button at the navigationView appear instead of the logout button